# change database to multisite in localhost

Tags: multisite

I have a WordPress installation to test before uploading to the server, but now I'm trying to make it Multisite.

I want to make the blog where I'm working on a subdomain but I don't want to delete all the posts I already have. I already have Multisite active.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I don't see any problem. The database will be updated, not overwritten. Anyway, make a DB dump and export your content as XML. If something bad happens, you'll be able to get everything back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just to clarify, you've already setup the multisite by following:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

And the multisite is working and you can create subdomains. But you want your current site to be a subdomain?

If so, I think the best way to do this will be to create the new sub site first, then use a cloning/migration plugin to copy all your data from your current site to the new sub site. WordPress has it's own export-import plugin:

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/

The WordPress Importer will import the following content from a WordPress export file:

- Posts, pages and other custom post types
- Comments
- Custom fields and post meta  (this will include your post thumbnails and  attachments).
- Categories, tags and terms from custom taxonomies
- Authors

Then you can remove all the data on your root site.

There are other cloning/migration plugins if you don't like the WordPress importer.